# 15 ohm resistance between 5V and ground is it short circuit?

Tags: schematics, motherboard, short-circuit

My Macintosh 7100 has 15 Ω resistance between 5V and ground so power supply goes to shutdown. Unfortunately I can't find any schematics for those machines, so I have no idea how to trace the fault.
Also there is an multilayer board and 5v rail mostly located in the middle layer.
I tested MOSFETs and they seems to be OK. A lot of ceramic caps show 15 Ω resistance between positive and negative.
I wonder if is it safe enough to make voltage injection test? And will it be sufficient to warm up faulty component with this resistance?

Processor on the board is Power PC 601 / 66 so it voltage is 3.9.

Comment: 15 ohms is not a short circuit. Have you seen the troubleshooting section of [Power Macintosh 7100 Series](https://www.applerepairmanuals.com/the_manuals_are_in_here/Power_Macintosh_7100_Series.pdf)?

Comment: I did all things mentioned in the document and nothing helped, also I tested power supply, I connected signal pin and it started with correct voltages. I tried to reseed the SIMM and replaced the battery. When I try to run the power supply connected to mac I get it stopped in one second. So it runs the fan then switches off it immediatelly.

Comment: Thank you I don't think that it is short. I measured the resistance on 5v rail on earlier 68000 mac and got 150 Ohm. So probably ot is OK resistance.

Comment: Then next, I suggest that you find videos of people repairing that model of computer—they are likely to show you what to look for and how to fix it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 2):

A 15 ohm resistance is not a short circuit. If there really is 15 ohms of resistance, that's only 0.333 A load.

However I highly doubt there really is a 15 ohm resistance, your multimeter just measures 15 ohms when you connect it to 5V and 0V terminals, and it is not even a resistance it is measuring but bunch of nonlinear circuits such as capacitors and logic chips.

Comment: Thank you, so it can be the correct resistance for internal chips, Am i right?

Comment: Thank you for reply!